# ArcGIS Online map freezing at certain locations

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps, chrome

When using the map view of ArcGIS Online I have encountered a number of locations which, when zoomed in to, will cause the web page to become sluggish, freeze, and typically be unresponsive for 30+ seconds. When the view is panned the web page will lock up again.

Limited testing has shown the issue occurs with at least the default 'Topographic' basemap with and without additional data loaded, starting at zoom levels around 14 or greater. Also it appears to affect Google Chrome but not Internet Explorer.

Example coordinates where this behavior has been noticed (long,lat to be pasted into the map view search box):

3.121, 53.869 - [link to location at a problem zoom level (17)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?center=3.121,53.869&level=17)

3.070, 53.246 - [link to location at a problem zoom level (17)](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?center=3.070,53.246&level=17)

Does anybody have insight into what may be causing these lockups or any solutions?